# How does c++ keep things in scope?

Tags: c++, sfml

To be more specific, I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Ball {
    public:
        unsigned collider_size;
        scionofbytes::MovementComponent movement;
        scionofbytes::GraphicComponent graphic;

        Ball(u_int init_collider_size, std::string texture_path) {
            collider_size = init_collider_size;
            movement = scionofbytes::MovementComponent();
            graphic = scionofbytes::GraphicComponent(
                    (u_int) collider_size/2,
                    (u_int) collider_size/2,
                    texture_path
            );
        }
};
```

I'm accepting the texture_path and passing it on to the graphic component, which looks like this:

```
class GraphicComponent {
    unsigned height;
    unsigned width;

    public:
        sf::Texture texture;
        sf::Sprite sprite;

        GraphicComponent() {}

        GraphicComponent(unsigned init_height, unsigned init_width, std::string texture_path) {
            width = init_width;
            height = init_height;

            texture.loadFromFile(texture_path);
            sprite.setTexture(texture);
        }
};
```

When I instantiate a ball object by passing in the texture_path, I'm creating a texture as a member of the graphic component and then assigning that texture to the graphic component's sprite member.

When using this sprite member to draw to the screen, I'm facing SFML's known [**white box problem**](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=8961.0).

Now from my understanding, of the ball objects stays alive, the graphic component member also stays alive as does the texture member of the graphic component.

So my question is, why does this not work? When using the sprite to draw on screen, I still get a white box. Why is the texture getting destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

In your `Ball` class constructor you are making a **copy** of your `GraphicComponent`. IIRC `sf::Sprite` only holds a reference to the `sf::Texture` so your copy may end up with the `sf::Sptite` pointing to the deleted `sf::Texture` from the object it got copied from.

Try constructing your `Ball` *without* making a copy of your `GraphicComponent`:

```
class Ball {
    public:
        unsigned collider_size;
        scionofbytes::MovementComponent movement;
        scionofbytes::GraphicComponent graphic;

        // Use initializer-list
        Ball(u_int init_collider_size, std::string texture_path)
        : collider_size(init_collider_size)
        , movement()
        , graphic((u_int) collider_size/2, (u_int) collider_size/2, texture_path)
        {
             // don't assign stuff here if you can avoid it
        }
};
```

*In addition* to that you may also want to create a **copy constructor** for your `GraphicComponent` class to prevent corruption elsewhere:

```
class GraphicComponent
{
    unsigned height;
    unsigned width;

public:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    GraphicComponent()
    {
    }

    GraphicComponent(unsigned init_height, unsigned init_width,
        std::string texture_path)
    {
        width = init_width;
        height = init_height;

        texture.loadFromFile(texture_path);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
    }

    // Give it a copy constructor
    GraphicComponent(GraphicComponent const& other)
    : height(other.height)
    , width(other.width)
    , texture(other.texture)
    , sprite(texture) // make it point to the new Texture not the other one
    {

    }
};
```